# How do I check in an ionic app if Observable<boolean>; is True or False

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

What I am attempting to do is listen for { Observable } from 'rxjs'; and run code on result

I use

.ts

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

public authenticationChange$: Observable<boolean>;

constructor( private auth: AuthService, ) {
  this.authenticationChange$ = auth.authenticationChange$;
}

runCodeIfLogginedIn() {
  console.log("hello I am logged in
}
```

html

```
ion-content>
  <div *ngIf="authenticationChange$ | async; else elseBlock">
    <ion-button (click)="logout()">Logout</ion-button>
  </div>

  <ng-template #elseBlock>
     <ion-button (click)="login()">Login</ion-button>
  </ng-template>
</ion-content>
```

When entering a page to see if the App is logging in or out from a auth service.  What I wish to do is check if

```
this.authenticationChange$
```

Is true in when it updates, and then run CodeIfLogginedIn() if true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.ts

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

public authenticationChange$: Observable<boolean>;
private isLoggedIn = false;

constructor( private auth: AuthService, ) {
  this.auth.authenticationChange$.subscribe((success) => {
    this.isLoggedIn = true;
  });
}

runCodeIfLogginedIn() {
  console.log("hello I am logged in
}
```

.html

```
ion-content>
  <div *ngIf="isLoggedIn; else elseBlock">
    <ion-button (click)="logout()">Logout</ion-button>
  </div>

  <ng-template #elseBlock>
     <ion-button (click)="login()">Login</ion-button>
  </ng-template>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some minor changing to Robert Rendells answer as I the page did not live up date with logging in and out

Here is what I changed

.ts

```
constructor( private auth: AuthService ) {
  this.authenticationChange$ = auth.authenticationChange$;
  this.authenticationChange$.subscribe((success) => {
    if(success == true ) { runCodeIfLogginedIn() }
  });
}
```

html

```
<ion-content>
  <div *ngIf="authenticationChange$ | async; else elseBlock">
     <ion-button (click)="logout()">Logout</ion-button>
  </div>

  <ng-template #elseBlock>
    <ion-button (click)="login()">Login</ion-button>
  </ng-template>
</ion-content>
```